# Compile SASS on server with PHP

Tags: php, sass

I have been looking all over the web, to see if there is some sort of way to compile SASS with php or AWS, so that I only have to worry about uploading 1 SASS file instead of a few css files, as the project has multiple devs uploading and having only 1 file to worry about makes things easier.

As expected, no results. Maybe I am, looking in the wrong places, So I turn to Stack-overflow, let me know if this is the wrong place to ask, ill take down the post.

Any information is appreciated

Comment: try with [sassphp](https://github.com/absalomedia/sassphp)